# Using HTML post without affecting the current page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

I am using the following form to send text messages from our Esendex account:

```
        <form method="post" action="https://www.esendex.com/secure/messenger/formpost/SendSMS.aspx">

        <P>Username:<br>
            <INPUT name="EsendexUsername" type="text"></P>
        <P>Password:<br>
            <INPUT name="EsendexPassword" type="password"></P>
        <P>Account:<br>
            <INPUT name="EsendexAccount" type="text"></P>
        <P>Recipient:<br>

            <INPUT name="EsendexRecipient" type="text"></P>
        <P>Message:<br>
            <TEXTAREA name="EsendexBody" rows="3" cols="20"></TEXTAREA></P>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

This is working fine, but when I submit the form it automatically goes to the Esendex page. What I need is to be able to post the information to the Esendex page, but leave the current page untouched because it has information like a stopwatch etc which need to carry on running.

Is there any easy way to do this? I don't need any reply from the Esendex website, just send the information to it and that's it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you’re a bit stuck, at least on the client side — JavaScript allows you to make HTTP POST requests, but only to the same domain that your web page is served from, which rules out sending data to Esendex.

You could submit the form to a script on your server, and get the server to send the HTTP POST to Esendex.

Comment: Not if you're doing cross-domain requests and I think it might be the case in this question.

Comment: @Rafael: you’re entirely right, I really should try to wake up before answering Stack Overflow questions. Answer corrected.

Comment: Hi paul thanks for your reply. Do you mean I would need to do this via AJAX and submit the details to another page on my domain which does all of the work with Esendex? Sorry I'm a bit useless when it comes to things like this

Comment: @Daniel: you’re most welcome, and no worries, there’s a few things going on here. You don’t *have* to use AJAX to submit the form to your domain — you could just make the form submit to the page it’s on, and just have the page return itself plus a little confirmation message. If you’re set on avoiding a page refresh though, then yup, you’ll need to submit via AJAX. And to communicate with Esendex outside of having the form submit directly there, yup, your server has to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can POST through an `<iframe>`.

```
<form action="something" target="iframe_id">

</form>
<iframe id="iframe_id" name="iframe_name" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Please note. This might fail some enterprise security tests.

Your other alternative is use AJAX using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Please note that AJAX would fail on cross-domain requests due to the browsers same-origin policy. Furthermore the request may fail on some browsers if the <iframe> is not visible ("display: none"). Safest way to implement this is using server side scripting (see answer by Paul D. Waite)